# PHP select lowest ID of Group

Tags: php, mysql

How can I call the lowest ID (nNr) and the entry next to it ($cPfad) in PHP? I have 2 Tables and try to get from both of them the Details of an ID.

My SQL

```
SELECT 
    p1.kArtikel, 
    p1.cName, 
    p1.cKurzBeschreibung, 
    p1.dLetzteAktualisierung, 
    p1.dErstellt, 
    p1.cSeo,
    p2.kartikelpict,
    p2.nNr,
    p2.cPfad
    FROM tartikel AS p1
    JOIN tartikelpict AS p2  
    ON (p1.kArtikel = p2.kartikelpict)
    JOIN (SELECT kartikelpict,  MIN(nNr) min_nNr FROM tartikelpict GROUP BY kartikelpict) p3
    ON (p2.kartikelpict = p3.kartikelpict AND p2.nNr = p3.min_nNr)
    ORDER BY p1.kArtikel
    DESC LIMIT 10
```

DB Tables

```
+----------+-------+---------------------+------------+-------+
| kArtikel | cName |  cKurzBeschreibung  | dErstellt  | cSeo  |
+----------+-------+---------------------+------------+-------+
|   560    | Title |   Short Description | 2014-03-25 | title |
+----------+-------+---------------------+------------+-------+

+--------------+--------------+-------+
| kartikelpict |     cPfad    |  nNr  |
+--------------+--------------+-------+
|     560      | picture4.jpg |   4   |
|     560      | picture3.jpg |   3   |
|     560      | picture2.jpg |   2   |
|     560      | picture.jpg  |   1   |
+--------------+--------------+-------+
```

My PHP Code

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    $cName = $row['cName']; 
    $cKurzBeschreibung = $row['cKurzBeschreibung']; 
    $dLetzteAktualisierung = $row['dLetzteAktualisierung'];
    $dErstellt = $row['dErstellt'];
    $cSeo = $row['cSeo']; 
    $date = strtotime($row['dErstellt']);
    $pubdate = date(r, $date);
    $id = $row['kArtikel'];
    $nNr = $row['p3.min_nNr'];
    $cPfad = $row['cPfad'];


echo"<item>";
echo"<title><?php echo $cName; ?></title>";
echo"<link>http://domain.com/".$cSeo."</link>";
echo"<guid isPermaLink='false'>http://domain.com/".$cSeo."></guid>";
echo"<pubDate>".$date."</pubDate>";
echo"<description><![CDATA[ <img src='http://domain.com/bilder/produkte/normal/".$row['nNr']."' />".$cKurzBeschreibung." ]]></description>";
echo"<enclosure url='http://domain.com/bilder/produkte/normal/'".$nNr." type='image/jpeg' />";
echo"       </item>";
}
```

The call of $cPfad does not output anything, the call of of $nNr call each ID instead of the lowest one to get the correct $cPfad. What am I doing wrong im my PHP Code?

Comment: you are embedding html directly into your php code. You have to atually `echo` it. For example `echo "<title>" . $cName . "</title>"`

Comment: Oh yess :) You are right.. Have copied the wrong part. Have correct it. Thanks

Comment: Also after your edit, if you close the `php` tag, typing `$cName` will just print that literal string. It is no longer a php variable

Comment: You mean while it is literal string it will not call from the lowest $nNr the $cPfad?

Comment: It is very unclear what your problem is right now. What is the actual output of your code right now and how does it differ from what you expect? If you don't show us some output it is difficult to help you

Comment: My PHP Code should select from DB Table the ID, from that the lowest $nNr ID and from the lowest $nNr the $cPfad from the row.
The result is here http://bit.ly/1sbw9oR You will send that the enclosure is not correct to the Image